# Multiple Domain Controller

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2012-r2, domain-controller

i need help on configuring this properly. 
we have 5 domain controller which 4 of them are located in different country and the other one is which is located in locally.

Problem:
PC cannot join to domain.

Setup:
local DC is set with DNS IP which is located remotely, connected via IPSec VPN. which on the other side of the firewall, they only allow the server IP to authenticate.

-DHCP server is on fortinet firewall.

-DNS IP is ISP DNS.

-Local server IP(192.168.76.11) is within local IP Subnet

-PC obtain dns is from firewall which is the ISP DNS.

when i configure the PC static IP and set the DNS as 192.168.76.11 it will authenticate. but ip obtain automatically which is the ISP DNS server, it will not authenticate because it is block when reaching the FQDN from the otherside firewall.

i need help setting this up to force user to authenticate to this local DC.
is there a way to do it in Windows server 2012 Std R2 or should i redirect the port traffic in firewall?

Comment: `PC obtain dns is from firewall which is the ISP DNS` - That's the problem. The PC's should use the AD DNS server.

Comment: thanks for confirming. but correct me if i am wrong. if the local DC is set with remote DNS server IP and i configure the firewall to set the DNS server with the IP of local DC, will the pc use the internet connection on the remote.

how can i configure the DNS server to use the local internet connection.

Comment: So long as the client PC's DNS servers are pointed to the local domain controller it doesn't matter where it gets it from.

Answer (score 2):

`ip obtain automatically which is the ISP DNS server`. That's what you need to change. Use your DNS server.

Comment: thanks for confirming. but correct me if i am wrong. if the local DC is set with remote DNS server IP and i configure the firewall to set the DNS server with the IP of local DC, will the pc use the internet connection on the remote. how can i configure the DNS server to use the local internet connection

Comment: It depends on how you configure DNS forwarders on your local DC/DNS server. If you want non-local DNS requests to use your ISP DNS server, that's what you should configure.

Comment: The client PC's DNS server must be the domain controller. The domain controller can have the DNS forwarders set to the ISP's DNS but the client must look to the domain controller for DNS resolution.